# Read http file content to string with Boost [C++]

Tags: c++, string, boost, webserver

I have to read the content of a file (in a webserver) to string in Visual Studio C++. I have a code which is working well on one webserver. But if I use another webserver, my program reads only the first 200 characters. Everything is same but the webserver.

This is the working URL: http://www.fxcoder.hu/fxc_esopus/clients.dat

And this is the max. 200 characters URL: http://www.forexhelpmate.com/app/webroot/forex/clients.dat

The clients.dat file is same on each server too.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
std::ostringstream ostringstream_content;
int GetPageContent(char* argv[]){
    try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(argv[0], "http");
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;
        // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
        while (error && endpoint_iterator != end){
            socket.close();
            socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
        }
        if (error) throw boost::system::system_error(error);
        // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
        // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
        // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
        boost::asio::streambuf request;
        std::ostream request_stream(&request);
        request_stream << "GET " << argv[1] << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << argv[0] << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        // Send the request.
        boost::asio::write(socket, request);
        // Read the response status line.
        boost::asio::streambuf response;
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");
        // Check that response is OK.
        std::istream response_stream(&response);
        std::string http_version;
        response_stream >> http_version;
        unsigned int status_code;
        response_stream >> status_code;
        std::string status_message;
        std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
        if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/"){
            std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (status_code != 200){
            std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
            return 1;
        }
        // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");
        // Process the response headers.
        std::string header;
        while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
            std::cout << header << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
        // Write whatever content we already have to output.
        if (response.size() > 0){
            ostringstream_content << &response;
        }
        // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
        while (boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error)) std::cout << &response;
        if (error != boost::asio::error::eof) throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e){
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What differences between the two web server could cause this problem?

Why would the second server only read the first 200 characters?

Thank you in advance.

Relative

---

Hungary, EU

Comment: The files are similar, not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stream the first part to `ostringstream_content` and the rest to `std::cout`.

The following correctly downloads both files for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int GetPageContent(char const *argv[]) {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(argv[0], "http");
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;
        // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
        while (error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
            socket.close();
            socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
        }
        if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error);
        // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
        // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
        // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
        boost::asio::streambuf request;
        std::ostream request_stream(&request);
        request_stream << "GET " << argv[1] << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << argv[0] << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        // Send the request.
        boost::asio::write(socket, request);
        // Read the response status line.
        boost::asio::streambuf response;
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");
        // Check that response is OK.
        std::istream response_stream(&response);
        std::string http_version;
        response_stream >> http_version;
        unsigned int status_code;
        response_stream >> status_code;
        std::string status_message;
        std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
        if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/") {
            std::cerr << "Invalid response\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (status_code != 200) {
            std::cerr << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
            return 1;
        }

        // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

        // Process the response headers.
        std::string header;

        while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
            std::cerr << header << "\n";

        std::cerr << "\n";
        std::cerr << "Writing content data\n";
        // Write whatever content we already have to output.
        if (response.size() > 0) {
            std::cout << &response;
        }

        // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
        while (true) { 
            size_t n = boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error);

            if (!error)
            {
                if (n)
                    std::cout << &response;
            }

            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                break;

            if (error)
                throw boost::system::system_error(error);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::cerr << "Done\n";
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char const* argv[] = { "www.fxcoder.hu", "/fxc_esopus/clients.dat" };
    //char const* argv[] = { "www.forexhelpmate.com", "/app/webroot/forex/clients.dat" };

    return GetPageContent(argv);
}
```